# C#: Locking a Queue properly for Iteration

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, queue, synchronized

I am using a Queue (C#) to store data that has to be sent to any client connecting.

my lock statement is private readonly:

```
private readonly object completedATEQueueSynched = new object();
```

only two methods are enqueueing:

1) started by mouse-movement, executed by the mainform-thread:

```
public void handleEddingToolMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    AbstractTrafficElement de = new...
    sendElementToAllPlayers(de)
    lock (completedATEQueueSynched)
    {
       completedATEQueue.Enqueue(de);
    }
}
```

2) started on a button-event, executed by mainform-thread too (does not matter here, but better safe than sorry):

```
public void handleBLC(EventArgs e)
{
    AbstractTrafficElement de = new...
    sendElementToAllPlayers(de);
    lock (completedATEQueueSynched)
    {
         completedATEQueue.Enqueue(de);
    }
}
```

this method is called by the thread responsible for the specific client connected. here it is:

```
private void sendSetData(TcpClient c)
{
    NetworkStream clientStream = c.GetStream();
    lock (completedATEQueueSynched)
    {
        foreach (AbstractTrafficElement ate in MainForm.completedATEQueue)
        {
            binaryF.Serialize(clientStream, ate);
        }
    }
}
```

if a client connects and i am moving my mouse at the same time, a deadlock occurs.
if i lock the iteration only, a InvalidOperation exection is thrown, because the queue changed.

i have tried the synchronized Queue-Wrapper as well, but it does't work for Iterating. (even in combination with locks)
any ideas? i just don't get my mistake

Comment: wonder if http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx this will wrk ?

Comment: Where exactly are you deadlocking? Without knowing who calls what in the overall picture it's hard to suggest what the synchronization issue is. Is the last part run when a new client connects? Remember also that raising an event from inside a lock is a bad idea - events are synchronous (by default), so you could raise something that calls some code outside the lock in another thread via an event handler, that then tries to re-enter your lock meaning your event call can never complete - deadlock!

Comment: I don't think you're actually deadlocking, just blocking (too) long.

Comment: You **never** want to use lock on a UI thread.  Lock implies blocking (even if it's for a very short time) and you **never** want to block the UI thread.  You can simply use a thread pool thread to invoke any code that needs to work with something shared between threads.  When it's done, just Control.Invoke to get back to the UI thread and perform any really quick UI updates.

Comment: If `completedATEQueue` isn't public, you can use that for the lock object instead of `completedATEQueueSynched`

Comment: @PeterRitchie - it is an established best-practice to lock on a helper object. Though usually with a simpler name.

Comment: @HenkHolterman it's an established best practice to lock on a *private* helper object.  `completedATEQueue` is private.  This best practice is because locking on an object that is not private could result it in being used as a lock object externally by other code for another reason, leading to deadlock.  See remarks for lock (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) and

Comment: But what if (a future version of) `Queue<>` does a `lock(this)` ? It's a mostly theoretical argument but you want to lock on something only your code has access to. `private` is not enough.

Comment: Iirc foreach doesn't actually dequeue; did you intend to dequeue? (you usually do, with a queue)

Comment: nope, i didn't - any new client must receive the whole queue.

so creating a new background worker who sends the data to the clients could help?
i noticed if the queue is small enough, it doesnt "deadlock"... can my code need so much time?^^

Comment: @HenkHolterman That doesn't make any sense since lock(this) **is an established anti-pattern**.  Something could reflect on your code and get at your lock object too; if we want to take to unlikely extremes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like [ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) you've wanted

**UPDATE**

Yes work fine, TryDequeue uses within the Interlocked.CompareExchange and SpinWait. Lock is not good choice, because too expensive take a look on [SpinLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.spinlock%28VS.100%29.aspx)  and don't forget about [Data Structures for Parallel Programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460718%28VS.100%29.aspx)

Her is enqueue from ConcurrentQueue, as you see only `SpinWait` and `Interlocked.Increment` are used. looks pretty nice

```
public void Enqueue(T item)
{
  SpinWait spinWait = new SpinWait();
  while (!this.m_tail.TryAppend(item, ref this.m_tail))
    spinWait.SpinOnce();
}

  internal void Grow(ref ConcurrentQueue<T>.Segment tail)
  {
    this.m_next = new ConcurrentQueue<T>.Segment(this.m_index + 1L);
    tail = this.m_next;
  }

  internal bool TryAppend(T value, ref ConcurrentQueue<T>.Segment tail)
  {
    if (this.m_high >= 31)
      return false;
    int index = 32;
    try
    {
    }
    finally
    {
      index = Interlocked.Increment(ref this.m_high);
      if (index <= 31)
      {
        this.m_array[index] = value;
        this.m_state[index] = 1;
      }
      if (index == 31)
        this.Grow(ref tail);
    }
    return index <= 31;
  }
```

Comment: does the de-queueing work fine with that?
and as im using a list to organize my connected clients, it would be better if i knew what i am doing wrong with my locks

Comment: Yes work fine, TryDequeue uses within the Interlocked.CompareExchange and SpinWait.

Comment: GSerjo,  your advice is very good, although acquiring a Lock per se is not a very expensive operation. The problem is addressed in the suggestion  given by @HenkHolterman: the lock is being held during a potentially slow operation (the network serialization).  Rewriting the code as Henk suggests will reduce contention for the queue and will probably give the expected results. :)

Comment: one last question:
what happens with a ConcuQueue when i enqueue while iterating?

Comment: as it turned out, the problem was that the server started sending new Elements (when i moved my mouse) while he was sending the old data at the same time, so the de- and serialisation stopped working.
thanks a lot for the concurrentQueue!
didnt read about SpinLocks yet, but as far as i see it the iteration works for the queue like it existed upon begin of iteration, right? 
so enqueued items while iterating wont appear in the iteration?

Answer (score 3):

You can reduce the contention, probably enough to make it acceptable:

```
private void sendSetData(TcpClient c)
{
    IEnumerable<AbstractTrafficElement> list;

    lock (completedATEQueueSynched)
    {
        list = MainForm.completedATEQueue.ToList();  // take a snapshot
    }

    NetworkStream clientStream = c.GetStream();
    foreach (AbstractTrafficElement ate in list)
    {
       binaryF.Serialize(clientStream, ate);
    }    
}
```

But of course a snapshot introduces its own bit of timing logic. What exactly does 'all elements' mean at any given moment?

Comment: Good suggestion! You just need to be aware that more elements could be enqueued while the network transmission is taking place, it's hard to say with the code given, but that might need to be addressed  =)

Comment: @sgorozco - that is what i am hinting at in the last paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

Henk Holterman's approach is good if your rate of en-queue, dequeue on queue is **not very high**. Here I think you are **capturing mouse movements**. If you expect to generate lot of data in queue the **above approach is not fine**. The lock becomes contention between the network code and en-queue code. **The granularity of this lock is at whole queue level**.

In this case I'll recommend what GSerjo mentioned - **ConcurrentQueue**. I've looked into the implementation of this queue. It is very granular. It operates at single element level in queue. While one thread is dequeueing, other threads can in parallel enqueue without stopping.

Comment: It seems to be only about Enqueue and GetEnumerator, that implies the rate of adding can't be very high.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I didn't get ur comment. With "rate of adding" I mean how many times the caller calls `Enqueue` per second. If that is high, your system's thread contention rate will go up.